# Handle MessageHandlingException from spring integration web service outbound-gateway

Tags: spring-integration

SI configuration of my application is like :

```
<oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="myMarshaller" contextPath="com.test" />

<int:gateway id="servgateway" service-interface="com.services.ServiceGateway" error-channel="error-channel">        
    <int:method name="getSum" request-channel="reqChannel" reply-channel="respChannel">         
    </int:method>
</int:gateway>
<int:chain input-channel="reqChannel" output-channel="respChannel">
    <int-ws:outbound-gateway uri="http://SER:IP/mokFault" message-sender="httpSender" marshaller="myMarshaller" 
    message-factory="soapMessageFactory"         />  
</int:chain>
<int:channel id="error-channel" />  

<int:service-activator input-channel="error-channel" ref="rrrorHandler" method="handleError"/>
```

Here this endpoint(SER:IP/mokFault) pointing to one SOAP Fault mock.

In Activator handling all exceptions. It's method looks like

```
public void handleError(Message<?> message) {

}
```

I tried to test this with juint, it's working fine and exceptions(SOAP Fault) are not coming in console.

If i call this gateway(servgateway) from my web application i am getting proper response 
but exceptions(SOAP Fault) are coming in IBM WS server console.  I haven't used any printStackTrace of exception/logger in code.

Only this spring integration web service outbound-gateway exceptions (SOAP Fault,UnKnownHost,Unmarshall...)are coming in server console.

Is there any more configurations required for remove all these exceptions from console??

I am using spring integration version 2.2.3.RELEASE.

Below is the exception list:

```
GatewayProxyF W org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport doSendAndReceive failure occurred in gateway sendAndReceive
                             org.springframework.integration.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [org.springframework.integration.ws.MarshallingWebServiceOutboundGateway#756f756f]
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:79)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain$1.send(MessageHandlerChain.java:154)
at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:288)
at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.send(MessagingTemplate.java:149)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:216)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.sendReplyMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:200)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.produceReply(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:165)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleResult(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:159)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:141)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain.handleMessageInternal(MessageHandlerChain.java:137)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:115)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:102)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:157)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:128)
at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:288)
at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:318)
at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.sendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:239)
at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.convertSendAndReceive(MessagingTemplate.java:274)
at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.doSendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:224)
at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.sendAndReceive(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:203)
at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invokeGatewayMethod(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:306)
at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.doInvoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:269)
at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:260)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
at $Proxy54.getSum(Unknown Source)
......................
Caused by: org.springframework.ws.soap.client.SoapFaultClientException: 1
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.client.core.SoapFaultMessageResolver.resolveFault(SoapFaultMessageResolver.java:37)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.handleFault(WebServiceTemplate.java:738)
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:564)
```

Comment: As you see it is `WARN`, so just turn off the 'warn' for `org.springframework.integration.gateway` category (or even for entire `org.springframework`) from your logging config. Or from WAS console, if you use it (by your comments)

Comment: i gave log4j.logger.org.springframework.integration = OFF in log4j. But still exceptions are coming in console. Do i need to configure anything in server?

Comment: `GatewayProxyF W` - it is WAS format. Try to turn off it from it's console: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wchelp/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.commerce.admin.doc%2Ftasks%2Ftlslogging.htm

Comment: Thanks Artem Bilan. Configured in WAS, now it's working fine .

Answer (score 0):

As you see it is WARN, so just turn off the 'warn' for `org.springframework.integration.gateway` category (or even for entire `org.springframework`) from your logging config. Or from [WAS console](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wchelp/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.commerce.admin.doc/tasks/tlslogging.htm), if you use it (by your comments).